# Can angularjs factory return something other than object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I am beginning to mess around with angular js.

I wrote this factory

```
mbg.factory('pollCall', function ($http, pollSettings) {
    return function (callback) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET', url: pollSettings.getUrl()
        }).success(function (response) {
            callback(response);
        }).error(function () {
            callback(false);
        });
    };
});
```

as you can see from it, it returns function rather than "return {};" object. This example works but I am thinking if it's possible way of designing a factory and if it won't break my app later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return anything with a factory and returning a function is fine. But in this context returning function is not required. You should use just return the promise value returned on `$http` invocation.

```
mbg.factory('pollCall', function ($http, pollSettings) {

        return {
           getData:function() {
                 return $http({method: 'GET', url: pollSettings.getUrl()});
           }
        };
}
```

In the controller just use the same success and error callback as you did it in service.

`pollCall.getData().success(...).error(...);`